# How to remove "data-w2p_disable_with" attribute when using A helper in web2py?

Tags: web2py

In my view file if I use the [`A`](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/05/the-views#Built-in-helpers) html helper it gets rendered with a strange attribute `data-w2p_disable_with`.

For example:

```
{{=A('test', _href=URL())}}
```

is rendered as:

```
<a href="/myapp/somecontroller/somefunction" data-w2p_disable_with="default">test</a>
```

1. What is the purpose of this attribute?
2. How can I remove it?

Answer (score 0):

That because web2py use its method to show the content.

For example:

```
<img src="{{=image.file}}" />
```

Once web2py process above code, the image will not be displayed. And data-w2p_disable_with="default" is added to the output html source.

So revise code as below:

```
<img src="{{=URL('download', args=image.file)}}" />
```

This time, you will not see data-w2p_disable_with="default" in html source(in your word, it was removed), and image was displayed in this example.